# trying a new 2016 openssl package, but still see the old 2012 version. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg, openssl

I'm trying to install a new 2016 open ssl package, but still see the old 2012 version, on Ubuntu 12.04 .

I have a bunch of Ubuntu 12.04 dedicated machines that can't connect to the internet. They're all running openssl 1.0.1 from 2012 (when running: `openssl version` I get: `OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012`).

I need the openssl upgraded to something new, so on a test machine with internet access, I've installed openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33_amd64.deb , a new pack from year of our lord 2016, with dpkg like so:

```
sudo apt-get download openssl
sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33_amd64.deb
```

The output is:

```
(Reading database ... 70268 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33 (using openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement openssl ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

That's it. I run: `openssl version` again and still see: `OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012`

I rebooted, just for the sake of it. Didn't help. I tried `sudo apt-get install openssl` and got

```
openssl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 354 not upgraded
```

*sigh* :-( Vat am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. The version you downloaded is *also* `1.0.1`. So why would you expect to see anything other than `1.0.1`? It's the same upstream release. The stuff before the `-` is the upstream release, namely `1.0.1` in this case.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmm. So let me axe you this - if my client (and I) want to see the actual package date, what do we do? aside from googling?

Comment: previous package installed was 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.5. I saw 7 Jan 2016 on the last update to 5.33, and I'm assuming it's the latest stable+safe pack since apt-get install openssl, and apt-cache show openssl suggested it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question is (if I understand it correctly) how one can find out the date of a package that has been modified by Debian, assuming the upstream version has not changed.

The Debian/Ubuntu package version number for upstream (non-native) software always consists of two parts. The part before the dash, which is the upstream number, and the one after the dash, which corresponding to changes made by Debian/Ubuntu. To see those Debian/Ubuntu specific changes, look at `/usr/share/doc/openssl/changelog.Debian.gz`. The Debian number (whatever that is called) may some of the time be reflected in the version string, but not always. If that is the case, the version string has probably been modified by Debian/Ubuntu. In this case, it appears it has not. To see a case where it has been, see

```
gcc --version
gcc-4.9.real (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

gcc points to gcc-4.9.

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# ls -lah /usr/bin/gcc  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 25  2015 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.9
```

And the version of the gcc 4.9 package on this system is:

```
dpkg -l gcc-4.9

||/ Name                              Version               Architecture          Description
+++-=================================-=====================-=====================-=======================================================================
ii  gcc-4.9                           4.9.2-10              amd64                 GNU C compiler
```

Comment: I see. So, to sum it up, in my case I wanna rely on the change logs/latest version number? The previous package that comes with the system was 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.5. I saw 7 Jan 2016 on the last update to 5.33, and I'm assuming it's the latest stable+safe pack since apt-get install openssl, and apt-cache show openssl suggested it. Is that it?

Comment: @Nahshonpaz I assume you are concerned about security patches. If you look at the changelog, namely `/usr/share/openssl/changelog.Debian.gz`, you'll see that there is a description corresponding to each change that has been applied by the distribution, including all security related changes. You can also run`apt-cache policy openssl` to see what versions of `openssl` are currently available in your sources. In Debian security updates come from `security.debian.org`. I'm not sure what Ubuntu does.

Comment: Cheers and a +1 @Faheem Mitha. Finally a (well hidden) place to see the changes and to be able to direct my managers/customers to.

Comment: Also note that changes made to most packages, by Debian at least, are security related fixes. There are exceptions, like `chromium`, but for the most case this is generally true.